# SQL how to remove a number from comma separated list, on multiple rows

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Lets say i have a table in my database there looks like this:

```
|-------------------------|
| id | numbers            |
|-------------------------|
|  1 | 1,3,5,7            |
|  2 | 2,4,6,8            |
|  3 | 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,6,8  |
|-------------------------|
```

I want to remove let us say 4 for all the rows that has the number 4 in the numbers column. What is the sql call to this? I'm using php and mysql.

Comment: Please change your table design. Never store multiple values in a single column

Comment: I don't know how many numbers the would be in all, so how is the prober way to store the values?

Comment: It looks like SQL (or an RDMS) might not be the right tool for the job.

Comment: What do the numbers, in the table, represent?

Comment: [First Normal Form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form) (and also to a certain extend [Database Normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) might be helpful links.

Comment: The numbers represent the id of a tag

Answer (score 1):

To make it more understandable I use different table and column names. A better table design would be

```
users table
-------------------
id
name
other_columns


roles table
-------------
user_id
role_number
```

Example data:

```
users
--------------
id    name   
1     peter
2     tom


roles 
----------
user_id   role_number
1         1
1         3
1         7
2         2
2         8
```

Using this design you can now query for all roles a user has like this

```
select r.role_number
from users u
join roles r on u.id = r.user_id
where u.name = 'peter'
```

or if you already have the users ID then

```
select role_number
from roles
where user_id = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [string functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html) you may try to write following query:

```
UPDATE
    `table_name`
SET
    `numbers` = TRIM(BOTH ',' FROM REPLACE(CONCAT(',', `numbers`), ',4', ''))
WHERE
    FIND_IN_SET('4', `numbers`);
```

*Test:*

```
SELECT TRIM(BOTH ',' FROM REPLACE(CONCAT(',', '4,2,3,4,5,6,7,6,8,4'), ',4', ''));
```

*Result:*

```
2,3,5,6,7,6,8
```

Comment: Doesn't work if you've got a number like 44 inside that csv list.

Comment: Unfortunately, Christian C is right. Tested with `SELECT TRIM(BOTH ',' FROM REPLACE(CONCAT(',', '4,2,44,3,4,5,6,7,6,8,4'), ',4', ''))` and the result is `24,3,5,6,7,6,8` which is too bad, because it messed up the numbers 2 and 44, making them 24 instead.